How to get rid of the back and forward button in firefox 126.0?
I tried to create a file in my profile folder: chrome/userChrome.css
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#back-button, #forward-button {
  display: none!important;
}

I also tried
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xul) {
  #back-button, #forward-button { display: none!important; } 
}

and
#nav-bar #back-button, #nav-bar #forward-button {
  display: none !important;
}

But none of this has any effect (even after firefox restart). I guess, this is the old way of achieving this (in firefox 58)

Note: if you are on this path, note that you won't have any more access to the back list dropdown

Try these CSS rules. If this doesn't work, it might be worth a Mozilla bug report.

BTW, every now and then Mozilla changes the names of objects... I've made userChrome.css rules that work on one version of Firefox (and Thunderbird) that have to be modified to work on a later version. sigh

You may need to enable user stylesheets before your userChrome.css is taken into effect.
In about:config, set toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true.
#back-button and #forward-button are still the correct IDs for these elements.
